# Why can Information be redirected but DeBug/Verbose cannot ? (They don't show on host by default)

Tags: powershell

The following pester test code is a good illustration of this problem.

```
PowerShell.exe -nologo -noProfile -Command 'Write-information "information"' | Should -BeNullOrEmpty

PowerShell.exe -nologo -noProfile -Command 'Write-DeBug "DeBug"' | Should -BeNullOrEmpty
            
(Write-information "information" *>&1) | Should -BeOfType 'System.Management.Automation.InformationRecord'

(Write-DeBug "DeBug" *>&1) | Should -BeNullOrEmpty
```

---

What is the reason for the poor behavior consistency of `write-information` compared to `write-DeBug`/`write-Verbose`?

After looking at the help document, I didn't find the answer, so I came here for help.

Comment: I feel that this may be a relatively advanced problem,I found this phenomenon after learning the help document for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

[Powershell Help - about_redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: I've read it, the question has not been mentioned.

Comment: You think it has been mentioned, please give the specific paragraph.